# Alter data from database before returning to view

Tags: php, laravel

I want to alter the file_name data before returning it to the view. Currently i'm doing:

```
$ci = CI::where('user_id',Auth::id())->get();
    return $$ci->map(function($item){
         return collect([
             'id' => $item->id,
             'title' => $item->title,
             'description' => $item->description,
             'file_name' => $this->archiving->url.'/media/content/'.$item->file_name // the part i need to alter
         ]);
 });
```

this works fine, but i need to put in the 'id,title,description'(basically all the other data that i'm not altering) or else the result will only give me the file_name. Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Accessors & Mutators`

```
class CI extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the file path
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFileNameAttribute($file_name)
    {
        return $this->archiving->url.'/media/content/'.$file_name;
    }
}
```

Check more abount [Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)

Comment: but $this->archiving->url is only available in the controller

Comment: select the answer please :)